# Passing value from One Php file to another

Tags: php, javascript

Does anybody know how to pass value from PHP file to JS file & then JS file to php file.Actually my PHP file called the JS file and then JS file called PHP file.Is it possible to pass the value from one PHP file to another without using form or link.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code to see how are you calling those files?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @AaronW. your message will probably get deleted automatically, but I agreed ;)

Comment: when you post a question , you need to elaborate it and if possible always shows some of your code

Answer (score 2):

can you clarify, the js is executing on client side or server side?

if the both php files are in the same server you can use A session variable ([Sessions reference on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)) and this way you dont need the js file;

if they are in diferennt server or you need to alter the values on the client side you could use json to print out the data, post it from the js file using ajax and then get it back in the next php file ([JSON reference on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write the JS file in PHP, passing variables that way.  Then you can use AJAX calls from the JS file to the PHP passing variables back that way.  There are many options, see this http://webcheatsheet.com/php/passing_javascript_variables_php.php

Answer (score 1):

You can POST some values from Javascript to a PHP page and it returns you a response. Then the same Javascript code takes this response and POST it to another PHP page.

Search $.post method of JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

One word: [Ajax](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Ajax&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=c03c33d1b643a9aa&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1231&bih=688)

And for ease of use: [JQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)